# How to get data from database but from the exact row?

Tags: mysql

I am using mysql. Now I want to write that query in which i will give mysql the row number then mysql will data from that column no only.

means..

if i have twenty rows in database but i want to get only 10th no of rows data? so how to write that kind query?

Comment: I'm a bit confused.  You state "i will give mysql the row number then mysql will data from that column no only."  Do you want data from an entire row or data from specific column in a row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an INT field named "ID" that is set to "Auto Increment."  This way each row will have a unique ID that you can use to select it.  Details about how to do this are located [here](http://library.creativecow.net/articles/chaffin_abraham/mysql-php-basics.php).

Answer (score 1):

Add a column with the AUTO_INCREMENT flag on it, so that this columns contains the row number for all your rows. MySQL does not really have support for fetching a row by number, only by column value.

Comment: but my problem is...that my data is coming in group by.. so if i add any new field in the database then also...it wont work..